# Two wins in a row in a game involving three players

Tags: probability

Three players, let's call them $A,B$ and $C$, play a game of chess. The first match is between $A$ and $B$. The winner will go on to play the third player (who is $C$ in the second match). The game continues until a player win $2$ matches in a row, who will be the eventual winner.

The chance for each player to win a match is one half.

Find the chance of winning the game for $A,B$ and $C$.

Comment: One approach is to develop a Markov chain (state transition matrix) model for this process.  After the first match the "state" is either that $A$ won or $B$ won.  In either case (their chances are equal) the winner is matched with $C$, and with probability one-half the first winner will win the second match and become "the eventual winner".  Etc.

Answer (score 4):

Let's deal with some notation first. Let $KL.M$ correspond to the probability of a situation that the current match is between $K$ and $L$, $K$ has won the previous game, and $M$ is the ultimate winner of the game. Here, the understanding of the probability is the conditional one with the condition being we already have arrived at the state where the $K$ has won the previous game and currently playing against $L$.

Now, in the first game, if $A$ wins, then the next state will have $AC.X$. If $A$ wins it is over, if $C$ wins we jump to a situation with $CB.Y$, and here if $C$ loses we jump to $BA.Z$ type of a situation. If $A$ wins we get back to our $AC.X$ situation again. Therefore, there are three relevant situation, $AC.X$, $CB.Y$ and $BA.Z$.

Here, we would have several equalities. For instance $AC.A$ would be the probability that $A$ wins conditional on the fact that $A$ won the previous game and would be playing with $C$. Now, the chances that $A$ wins right away is equal to $1/2$. The chances that $A$ wins after a loss to $C$ would be equal to $CB.A\times 1/2$ where we multiply by 1/2 because we jump to the state $CB$ with $1/2$ probability. Then you would observe that $AC.A=1/2+CB.A$. The chances for $AC.B$ would correspond to a situation where $A$ necessarily loses to $C$ and $B$ wins after the $CB$ state, which would equal to $1/2 \times CB.B$. We can make these calculations for $9$ different situations which would yield
$$
\begin{align}
AC.A &=& 1/2+CB.A\\
AC.B&=&1/2 CB.B\\
AC.C&=&1/2 CB.C \\
CB.A &=& 1/2 BA.A\\
CB.B&=&1/2 BA.B\\
CB.C&=&1/2+1/2 BA.C \\
BA.A &=& 1/2 AC.A\\
BA.B&=&1/2+1/2 AC.B\\
BA.C&=&1/2 AC.C \\
\end{align}
$$
So you have $9$ equations in $9$ unknowns here.

Next, you would look at the situations with $B$ winning in the first round. Then your states would look like $BC.X, CA.Y, AB.Z$ which again would yield similar $9$ equations in $9$ unknowns.

Now, the probability that $A$ wins is equal to $1/2\times AC.A + 1/2 \times BC.A$, for $B$ this would equal $1/2\times AC.B + 1/2 \times BC.B$, and for $C$ we would have $1/2 \times AC.C+1/2\times BC.C$. The reasoning is quite straightforward. For $A$, there are two cases in the beginning, with $1/2$ probability we would get to the state $AC.X$ and with $1/2$ chance we would end up with $BC.Y$. Similar arguments would imply the other equalities.

Comment: I'm up-voting because you took my suggestion (perhaps merely by coincidence) and ran with it.  Unfortunately you've stopped short of answering the problem with this setup, which the other two Answers (so far) settled.

Answer (score 3):

Clearly the chance that $A$ and $B$ win is the same by symmetry.  Let the chance that $C$ wins be $c$.  When $C$ plays the first game, if he loses the match is over.  If he wins twice in a row he wins the match.  If he wins one and loses the next, there is $\frac 12$ chance the match will be over before he plays again. If not, he is in the same position as in his first game.  So $c=\frac 14$ (that he wins his first two games) $+\frac 18c$ (that he wins the first, loses the second, then wins eventually).  This gives the result that $c=\frac 27=\frac 4{14}$, while the chance for each of $A,B$ is $\frac 5{14}$.

Answer (score 2):

TL,DR: $P(A) = 5/14$, $P(B) = 5/14$, $P(C) = 4/14$.

Let $W_A$, $W_B$, and $W_C$ be the states corresponding to wins for $A$, $B$, and $C$.

Let $AB$ be the state where $A$ won the previous match, and is currently facing $B$ (and so on for $AC$, $BA$, etc.).

Let $N$ be the starting state.

We have ten states. The transition rates between states are as follows:

$P(W_A \rightarrow W_A) = 1$, and similarly for $W_B$ and $W_C$. Once someone wins, they've won forever.

$P(AB \rightarrow BC) = 0.5$, and $P(AB \rightarrow W_A) = 0.5$, and similarly for $AC$, $BA$, etc.

$N \rightarrow AC$ with probability $0.5$, and $N \rightarrow BC$ with probability $0.5$.

This is a Markov chain. We want to get the *stationary state* of the Markov chain. One way to do this is to enter all the transition rates into a matrix:
$$
\begin{array}{ccccccccccc}
    & N & AB & AC & BA & BC & CA & CB & W_A & W_B & W_C\\
N   & 0 & 0 & 0.5&0 & 0.5&0 & 0 & 0 & 0 &  0 \\
AB  & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0.5&0 & 0 & 0.5&0 &  0 \\
AC  & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0.5&0.5&0 &  0 \\
BA  & 0 & 0 & 0.5&0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0.5& 0 \\
BC  & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0.5&0 & 0 & 0.5& 0 \\
CA  & 0 & 0.5&0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 &  0.5\\
CB  & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0.5&0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 &  0.5\\
W_A & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 &  0 \\
W_B & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 &  0 \\
W_C & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 &  1 
\end{array}
$$ 
In this matrix, rows are starting states and columns are end states. So $(N,AC)$ is actually $P(N \rightarrow AC)$.

By multiplying the matrix by itself many times, we can get the end state probabilities. Ideally we want to find the limit as we multiply the matrix by itself infinitely many times, but numerical solutions will usually do.

In this case, we get the stationary matrix:

$$
\begin{array}{ccccccccccc}
    & N & AB & AC & BA & BC & CA & CB & W_A & W_B & W_C\\
N   & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 5/14 & 5/14 & 4/14\\
AB  & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 8/14 & 4/14 & 2/14\\
AC  & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 8/14 & 2/14 & 4/14\\
BA  & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 4/14 & 8/14 & 2/14\\
BC  & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 2/14 & 8/14 & 4/14\\
CA  & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 4/14 & 2/14 & 8/14\\
CB  & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 2/14 & 4/14 & 8/14\\
W_A & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0\\
W_B & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0\\
W_C & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 
\end{array}
$$

We care about $P(W_A|N)$, $P(W_B|N)$, and $P(W_C|N)$, i.e. the probabilities that each person wins given that the game starts in state $N$. These three states correspond to the three entries in the upper right corner of the matrix entries $(N,W_A)$, $(N,W_B)$, and $(N,W_C)$.

Comment: Why don't you say $5/14$? It's more accurate, more informative, and shorter than $.35714$ !

Comment: Because I calculated it numerically, and just copied the resulting matrix over. But your way is better, and it's fixed now.

Answer (score 0):

Since $A$ and $B$ must have equal chances, we shall focus on $C$.

Using the symbols $W,L,N$ to indicate *Win*, *Loss*, *Not-in-match*, we can chart $C's$ course.

Note that if a player is not in a match:

- she has to necessarily win her next match else someone else will
- she can win only $2$ matches later at the earliest.
- it is immaterial (for $C$) who wins the *first* match

So $C$ can win like $NWW,\;\; NWLNWW,\;\; NWLNWLNWW$ etc

This is an infinite $G.P.$ with $a = 1/4, r = 1/8, S(\infty) = \frac{1/4}{1-1/8}= \frac27$

The rest gets equally divided between $A$ and $B$

$P(A) = 5/14,\;\; P(B) = 5/14,\;\;P(C) = 2/7$

Answer (score 0):

After the first match (between $A$ and $B$), there will be a latest *winner*, a *next* opponent, and a latest *loser*.  Let's let $w$, $n$, and $\ell$ denote the probability of the game eventually being won by the latest winner, next opponent, and latest loser, respectively.  Note that our main interest is in $n$, since the game begins with $C$ as the next opponent, regardless of the outcome of the first match.

Now if the game does not end with the latest winner beating the next opponent, which happens with probability $1/2$, then the next opponent becomes the latest winner, the latest loser becomes the next opponent, and the latest winner becomes the latest loser.  This implies $n={1\over2}w$ and $\ell={1\over2}n$.  But we must have $w+n+\ell=1$, and thus

$$2n+n+{1\over2}n=1$$

which solves to $n=2/7$.